# send form via email in orbeon forms

Tags: email, orbeon, xforms

I'm new with xforms platform. I would like to send my form via email. I have got a form application based on your tutorial. But I wanna to send my form results via email. Can anyone explain me (as for dummie;)) how can I add email button and configure it to send emails? I found info about email proccessor but I dont know where to insert the code and how to trigger it to button in form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Form Runner, which does all the work for you out of the box. See the following [documentation on email properties](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Email-settings).

And here is the [Form Runner code that sends email](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/email/email-form.xpl), using the Email processor. It's not rocket science but it's not explained in just a few minutes.